Was the use of police officers to block MPs from entering the National Assembly of Korea constitutional/legal?
Was the use of police officers to block MPs from entering the National Assembly constitutional?
Was the use of police officers to block MPs from entering the National Assembly legal?

TV footage showed police officers blocking the entrance of the National Assembly and soldiers carrying rifles in front of the National Assembly's main building.

https://www.abc.net.au/news/2024-12-04/south-korean-president-yoon-suk-yeol-declares-martial-law/104681360?sf275656263

The imposition of martial law generally presumes that certain elements of the normal legislative process have been suspended, so unless the constitution specifically allows martial law, asking about details in the execution is kind of a moot point.  It's a bit like asking whether it's legal to take hostages during a bank robbery.

The ROK constitution does have explicit provisions for martial law; see Article 77. I'm no scholar of this subject either but it took me 3 minutes to find online.

The Supreme Court has stated they will review the situation.
